# Getting an error in a Spring boot MVC app that uses a taglib library

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

First post here. I am trying to update a Spring boot app to Java 20 / Tomcat 10.1

It uses a third party TLD library.

When I run the app I get the following error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:496)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:475)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:121)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:496)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:475)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadFromParent(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:113)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.doLoadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165) ...
```

Any idea of what I may be missing?  thank you!

The following are included in the POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
</dependency>

    
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What is the library? How did you use it?

Comment: pd4ml a library to create PDFs.  We use it to convert jsp pages to PDFs

Comment: It didn't use Jakarta servlet spec.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a library. Have you tried to check with `mvn dependency:tree` command if you got this library included in your project? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/jsp-api/2.0

Comment: I tried doing a mvn depencecy:tree and got a "BUILD SUCCESS" no errors or warnings.

Comment: You need to take a look at the command output and check if you have the javax.servlet.jsp library included in your project. If not, you need to add this dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by using the tomcat migration tool.

The link to the tool is found in this page: https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html

The tool updates all the namespaces.  After running the third party api through the migration tool, the resulting jar file worked as expected.

It is as simple as running this command:

```
java -jar jakartaee-migration-*-shaded.jar <source> <destination>
```